# add the last digits in a number list in python

Tags: python, typeerror

I am taking a course on pyschools trying to learn Python. The question asks to input a list of numbers and add the last digit of the numbers entered. Here is the code I came up with. No laughing(I'm new). The code works in my version Python 2.7.5. However, I get an error on their site. Is there a better way to add the last number in a list? I think I am casting a list as an integer and their site doesn't like that, but I don't know for sure. I appreciate your help, thank you.

```
def getSumOfLastDigits(numList):
    total = 0
    for num in numList:
        total += int(num[-1])
    return total

input_Nums = raw_input('Enter the list of numbers: ').split(',')

print getSumOfLastDigits(input_Nums)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Code", line 4, in getSumOfLastDigits
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Comment: Thanks @Jared. I should have learned SO formatting before posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your numList is a list of string, then you shouldn't get that error based on the code you provided. Otherwise, if it's a list of numbers, then you cannot access the last digit of an integer with `num[-1]`. What instead you can do is to take the modulo of 10:

```
def getSumOfLastDigits(numList): 
    total = 0 
    for num in numList: 
        total += num % 10
    return total
```

Comment: `raw_input` provides a string and OP doesn't convert until after indexing

Comment: I think OP might have confused himself whether he used string or int, the code he provided doesn't produce any error.

Comment: Holy Hannah, that was awesome. Great bit of knowledge, perfect answer. I really appreciate that lightning quick response cheeyos. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why the error occurs and it shouldn't occur. To achieve your goal, there is more pythonic way.

For a list of ints:

```
>>> ints = [10, 11, 12, 11110, 112]
>>> sum(x % 10 for x in ints)
5
>>>
```

For a string containing numbers seperated by ,:

```
>>> ints = '10, 11, 12, 11110, 112'
>>> sum(int(x[-1]) for x in ints.split(','))
5
>>>
```

Comment: I can't thank you all enough. The pythonic way is cool. I didn't understand before that I was accepting the numbers as a string. I assumed they were a list of numbers. I think the learning site wanted me to do it the numeric way, not the string way I had used. This is great information. Thanks for going easy on me.